# Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type <MyClass>

Tags: c#, json.net

This code:

```
var commandMessage = new CommandMessage { CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid() };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(commandMessage);
var myCommandMessage = (CommandMessage)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

gives this error message:

```
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'QueueConnectionStringTester.CommandMessage'
```

This is the CommandMessage class:

```
public class CommandMessage
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }        
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show your `CommandMessage` class?

Comment: yes I posted it the code for the CommandMessage class. It there :-)

Comment: Why not just use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json,commandMessage.GetType());` ? Seems like thats what the documentation wanst you to do: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to specify the type when deserializing.

Either:

```
var myCommandMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CommandMessage>(json);
```

Or:

```
var myCommandMessage = (CommandMessage)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(CommandMessage));
```

Comment: Nice, simple answer. Just out of interest: when using the non-generic `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` method, what type is returned? Is it an `object`, or is it using the type of `T` from the generic signature? In which case, what would `T` be - `null`?

Comment: @GeoffJames The non-generic version of DeserializeObject returns `object` which you then need to cast to the type you are expecting, as shown in my answer above (the second example).  If you use the overload without a type parameter (as the OP was doing), then a JObject will be returned.

Answer (score 5):

You need to give the type. JsonConvert class does not know anything about your CommandMessage class

```
    public class CommandMessage
    {
        public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var commandMessage = new CommandMessage { CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid() };
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(commandMessage);
        var myCommandMessage =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CommandMessage>(json);
    }
```